# I have worked & reworked the strbody block, still I receive compiling errors. I've also mirrored the code to other programs and still receive errors

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, html-email

```
    trbody = "Good Morning " & Cells(i, 15).Value + "," _
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                    & "Can you please verify if the following check(s) are still outstanding?" + _
                    vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                    & "Check # " + Cells(i, 1).Value + "-- " + "Check Date: " & Cells(i, 6).Value & "-- " + "Net Amount: $" + Cells(i, 6).Value + "-- " + Cells(i, 2).Value + _
                     vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine + _
                     "Regards," + _
                    vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
```

Example intended output:

```text
    Good Afternoon Emily,
    
    Can you please verify if the following check is still outstanding?
    
    Check # 1000000– Check Date: 12/15/22– Net Amount: $2,431.52– Schwartz, Melvin
    
    
    Regards,
```

Comment: First of all, use `&` to concatenate, not `+`.

Comment: You may also wish to read up on the VBA String Method (Not not string type)

Comment: You may also wish to say what the compilation error message(s) are.

Comment: Will compile if you remove that last `_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code *works* like a charm on my side:

```
rbody = "Good Morning " & Cells(i, 15).Value & "," _
                    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                    & "Can you please verify if the following check(s) are still outstanding?" & _
                    vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                    & "Check # " & Cells(i, 1).Value & "-- " & "Check Date: " & Cells(i, 6).Value & "-- " & "Net Amount: $" & Cells(i, 6).Value & "-- " & Cells(i, 2).Value & _
                     vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                     "Regards,"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Custom Email Body Generation

[image]

```vb
Sub GenerateEmailBody()

    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Const DATA_DELIMITER As String = " - "

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    If LastRow < FIRST_ROW Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim EmployeeName As String, AccountNumber As String, DateString As String
    Dim NetAmount As String, LastName As String, FirstName As String
    
    Dim trBody As String, i As Long
    
    For i = FIRST_ROW To LastRow
        EmployeeName = ws.Cells(i, "O").Text
        AccountNumber = ws.Cells(i, "A").Text
        DateString = ws.Cells(i, "F").Text
        NetAmount = ws.Cells(i, "G").Text
        LastName = ws.Cells(i, "C").Text
        FirstName = ws.Cells(i, "B").Text
    
        trBody = "Good Morning " & EmployeeName & "," _
            & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "Can you please verify " _
            & "if the following check(s) are still outstanding?" _
            & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "Check # " & AccountNumber & DATA_DELIMITER _
            & "Check Date: " & DateString & DATA_DELIMITER _
            & "Net Amount: " & NetAmount & DATA_DELIMITER _
            & LastName & ", " & FirstName _
            & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "Regards," _
            & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "Your Boss"
    
        Debug.Print trBody
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Result**

```
Good Morning Emily,

Can you please verify if the following check(s) are still outstanding?

Check # 1001 - Check Date: 04/25/2023 - Net Amount: $5,000.00 - Schwartz, Melvin



Regards,

Your Boss
Good Morning Peter,

Can you please verify if the following check(s) are still outstanding?

Check # 1002 - Check Date: 05/01/2023 - Net Amount: $10,000.00 - Wick, John



Regards,

Your Boss
Good Morning Marg,

Can you please verify if the following check(s) are still outstanding?

Check # 1003 - Check Date: 04/22/2023 - Net Amount: $250.00 - Tano, Ahsoka



Regards,

Your Boss
```